# classic asp, excel, stop leading 0 (zero's) from being removed

Tags: excel, asp-classic

I'm populating an excel worksheet with the results of a query.  In the results set is a 'Description' field which can basically have anything in it, including numbers prefixed with leading zero's, such like 0000234.  The problem is that in writing them to a cell, the leading zero's are getting knocked off, so in the case above I end up with 234.  How do I ensure that it is treated as a text string and what ever is in the description field is simply pasted in as is?

The line used is:

```
 Response.Write vbTab & ResultSet(8,r)
```

Thanks R.

Answer (score 7):

Evidently you found a solution to this, given [your follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197725/how-to-format-line-so-that-i-end-up-with-08075).

For the benefit of anyone else reading this, the solution was to wrap the result in an Excel formula that simply evaluates as a string literal.  For example, if your data is 0000234 and you want it to be a 7-character text value, you should give Excel

```
="0000234"
```

The ASP code in the original question should be (and was eventually) modified to

```
Response.Write vbTab & "=""" & ResultSet(8,r) & """"
```

(Within a string, literal quotation marks must be doubled.)

Answer (score 0):

Prefix the content with an apostrophe.

Comment: This will prevent Excel from treating the content as a number, but it will also inject a literal apostrophe into the content.

Comment: @John: Yes, I agree. Apologies. I should have tried it first.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a template sheet that you programatically open and fill with data, format the column as Text.