# Format line so that I end up with ="08075"

Tags: asp-classic

How many " (double quotes) do I put around this line so that I end up with ="08075" being pasted into my excel worksheet?  The line is:

```
Response.Write vbTab & ResultSet(8,r)
```

I need and '=' sign with a single quote before the ResultSet(8,r) with a closing double quote after... I tried:

```
Response.Write vbTab & "="" & ResultSet(8,r) & """
```

but that didn't work, plus a couple others but that didn't work, the number of quotes thing always gets me so if someone wants to give me a general rule of thumb on this one I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 4):

To get a literal double quote (`"`) inside of a string in VBScript, you need to use two double quotes (`""`).  So for your example:

```
Response.Write vbTab & "=""" & ResultSet(8,r) & """"
'                      ^   ^                    ^  ^ These delimit the string
'                        ^^                      ^^  These create literal quotes
```

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't you know, I just cracked it:

```
Response.Write vbTab & "=""" & ResultSet(8,r) & """"
```

Thanks, R.

Comment: Funny how a simple syntax highlighter (even the SO one) reveals the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Double each quote you want to end up in the string. So what you want would be:

```
Response.Write vbTab & "=""" & ResultSet(8,r) & """"
```